# Motor Constants - Formulas

Tags: motor, brushless-dc-motor

I have some problems verifying the motor constants in the table below.
From my knowledge, the following formula holds between the torque constant
and the BEMF constant:

[image]

Now, in the datasheet mostly it is not clear, if the torque constant is in peak or RMS and the same goes for the voltage constant.

When I now use the formula for the BEMF constant of 9.8V/krpm (assume RMS), when I get a torque constant of 0.162Nm/A peak and 0.1146Nm/A rms. So the 0.133Nm/A from the datasheet do not match with one of them.

So, did I miss something? There is also a deviation for other motors from other manufacturers when I apply the formulas, still it seems to be always pretty good in range.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between your calculation and the datasheet is not suspiciously big in my opinion. The manufacturer probably measured each value independently and didn't just calculate one from the other (the ratio between torque and back-EMF constant isn't always exactly the same throughout the table). So there is some difference to be expected (measurement errors, non-ideal behavior of the motor, ...).

From my experience back-EMF and torque constant are usually noted in peak values, although this doesn't provide an explanation for the difference between torque and back-EMF constant as most likely the same convention is used for both values.